# meaning of "just place order"

Tags: phrase-meaning

what does "just place order" mean in this sentence?

> do you want to just place your order at once or what?

I thought it might mean to determine an address or maybe simply mean "order"?
what does the whole sentence mean?

Comment: Someone is asking you, very rudely, if you wish to buy something from them. The correct answer is "I'll think about it."

Comment: @Mick I prefer _"How many times shall I fold the order before I tell you where to insert it?"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Place an order](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/place+an+order)*** is an idiomatic expression that means:

> - to submit an order.
>
>   - *My secretary placed an order for a new computer. I placed my order only yesterday.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

They are asking, with a tone that sounds impolite, if you want to make an order immediately or not.